# Svelte FSM-like complex navigation schema

Tags: javascript, stack, svelte, store

Have you ever read about strong Svelte stores theory ? Something like Proxies inside reactivity ?

I'm trying to implemenet a stacked context tracking system, for using with FSM-like components navigation schema, for those environments with poor routing abilities, such as mobile games...

EDIT: I flattened / merged my 3 FSMs into one ... no more need to have nested FSMs !! (see long answers below)

My usecase: I have a set of components folders 'outer' and 'inner' grouping views of a FSM like navigation components. Each folder stores various components, and an index TOC written like this:

```
// src/lib/outer/index.js
import { default as A } from './A.svelte'
import { default as B } from './B.svelte'
import { default as C } from './C.svelte'

const lookups = new Map ()

// aliasing components...
lookups.set ('A', A)
lookups.set ('B', B)
lookups.set ('C', C)

// get a compo by its alias
export const view = (name) => lookups.get (name)
```

Doing things like this, you can grab easily some components and import them as as well:

```
// src/lib/fsm-system/FSMViews.svelte

 <svelte:component this={ ctx.$view } { ctx } />
 
 <script lang="ts">
    export let ctx = null
 </script>
```

The user-calling code could seem to:

```
// src/routes/merged.svelte
<h1> Mergeable FSM test </h1>

<FSMiews { ctx } />

<script lang="ts">
    import { FSMContext, FSMViews } from '$lib/fsm-system'
    import { view } from '$lib/outer' // SvelteKit for my tests...

    const ctx = FSMContext ({ debug: true })
    const data = { x: 42 }

    ctx.push ({ view, data })
    ctx.show('A')   
</script>
```

The trick is to write proplerly FSMContext, a special component that:

- is a stack array, each level holding an FSM context (current view + payload data)
- is reactive (writable or derived)
- could use JS proxies

... but for the moment I m unable to track properly the ending item of the stack which is supposed to hold:

- the current viewname
- the currenr level TOC function (from outer/index.js)
- the stored payload for this level

Does anyone have some suggestions or comments ?

Answer (score 0):

I had 3 navigation FSM-like schemas for my app views:

- Game steps: Create/Join/Play/GameOver... 8+ states
- multiplayer Turn plies (nested): 10 states
- single player gameplay action (nested again): 5+ states

I decided to merge them manually. Only turn FSM views sequence is like the attachment image.

just remember one thing: of you plan to use svelte:component directive with a lot of subviews, probably driven by n underlying store, such as  UI wizards or tabbed panes, you can easily prepare a Table-Of-Contents (index) for all your subsequent subviews folders. Saying:

```
// src/lib/wizard/index.js
import SubView1 from './SubView1.svelte'
import SubView2 from './SubView2.svelte'

...

import SubView10 from './SubView10.svelte'

const lookups = new Map ()
lookups.set ('sv1', SubView1)
....
lookups.set ('sv10', SubView10)

export const index = (svname) => lookups.get (svname)
```

Like that, you avoid polluting/bloating main caller view namespace scope.

This also could ensures a basoc 'routing'  in systems like SPA or mobile ones... and could prevent cheating by direct URL altering in the browser.

Enjoy coding !

[image]